# Umbraco ?umbDebugShowTrace=true not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco

Hello I have  in the AppSettings of the web.config file and using Umbraco 4.6.1.

I go to page that takes way to long to load initially, so I append ?umbDebugShowTrace=true to the page, but it doesn't output anything that tells me anything about a stack trace.  I also have the following in the web.config file:

`<trace enabled="true" requestLimit="10" pageOutput="true" traceMode="SortByTime" localOnly="true" />`

within the `<system.web>` tag.

How do I get information on why a page is taking too long to load initially?

Answer (score 9):

Try to set the next key in AppSettings section:

```
<add key="umbracoDebugMode" value="true" />
```

Comment: Yes, I have done this also.  Still not showing anything!

Answer (score 0):

If you use Firefox you can add the y-slow add on might be able to pick up anything else that might not be picked up by the debug trace.

Comment: This plugin does not tell me what code on the server is taking too long to execute.